# Как зеркально отразить персонажа при движении?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Я не могу найти как зеркально отразить персонажа в своей игре. Помогите пожалуйста! (язык C#)

Answer (score 1):

1. создать камеру
2. создать Render Texture
3. прилепить ее в камеру (в Camera Target)
4. применить текстуру на обьект (на куб или плейн, например)
5. изменить у обьекта скейл по нужной оси с 1 на -1

вот так и получится зеркало.

---

Если вопрос как флипнуть персонажа то измени скейл у персонажа по нужной оси с 1 на -1

Comment: В тегах стоит 2d и мне не сильно кажется что ему нужно именно зеркало) Скорее вопрос как Flip'нуть персонажа в другую сторону